# python selenium xpath Как получить элементы внутри другого элемента

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[image: Вот структура страницы]

Я получаю все строки таблицы:`//table[@class='table']//tr`
Затем я прохожу по всем строкам таблицы в цикле и пытаюсь достать все td для каждой строки:

```
rows = self.table_form.get_all_rows()
        for row in rows:
            call = row.find_elements_by_xpath("//td")
```

Но в итоге достаются все td на странице а не только те что находятся в данной строке. Как можно это исправить ?

Comment: Вы рано обрезали результат xpath:
//table[@class='table']//t

До // - должно быть уточнение, в какой именно таблице искать позиции td
Дайте ссылку на сайт, что вы пытаетесь распарсить - так будет проще понять, как сделать верно

Comment: Там только одна таблица

Comment: он локальный, не могу дать ссыль

Comment: call = row.find_elements_by_xpath("//td")  - вот тут, Вы сразу ищете с помощью xpath все теги <td>, но сперва, вам, на сколько я понял, нужно зайти в <tr>, код должен иметь вид tr[1]/td - для конкретной строки, а для цикла tr[row]/td

Comment: Но rows это все tr, а отдельный row это WebElement тот же отдельный tr, и внутри него я вызываю find_elements_by_xpath